# Git Pre Commit Hook -- Dump file changes into a file

Tags: git

Ive been making a cms of late that uses Github API to work with a local update script (php). This script reads all the file changes and then gets the raw data of each file, and updates the cms files... The problem is, github API lacks when it comes to renamed files.

My solution to this is to create a pre-commit hook that gets all of the file changes, and dumps the information into 1 file that can be more descriptive when it comes to file renaming. Is this possible? I prefer maybe if the information can be stored in a json array so it can be read by php directly? If this is possible, how would i write such a script? i know some python, but not much about ruby or bash. Any help is appreciated!